# Can we compare value of a field in 2 different urls using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, automation

I know we can capture the value of a field for each url individually. But is it also possible to compare the value captured for the same field in 2 different urls using Selenium tool for validation?

I searched over the web but did not get any conclusive results. Please advice.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, Go to the first url and get the value of field and browser to second url and get the value of the field and store it in a variable then compare it using assert.

Comment: Thanks. But using assert for  every  test case will make testing very slow. Is there a solution when the field value can be compared and validated for  a large number of test cases when using 2 different urls ?

Comment: Also can assert be used to compare values across 2 different urls for a particular field?

Comment: yes, you can use it to compare values

Comment: thank you ..can you also advice on the other question  on how can we handle the slow speed of testing if we assert every test case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to compare the value of field from two different URL's

1). Visit the First URL-> Read the field value and store it in a Variable
2). Visit the Second URL -> Read the field value and store it in a variable
3). Compare the Values

Comment: Can the compare be done parallelly in both the urls ?  I am trying to use selenium to automate the below process: 1)get the field value from url1 2)get field value from url2  3) compare the values from url 1 and url 2 for all the test cases for pass and fail. Based on the above selenium tool should create a report with field value from url 1,field value from url 2 and pass/fail (for all the test cases) .

Comment: What do you mean by parallely.
Do you have the desired value already with you or you need to pick value from one source and then compare with another source?